# Cannot get data (100k+ rows) for a dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Pretty new to the dynamoDb and the whole AWS, it's very exciting but I feel the learning curve is a bit steep. Anyway, here is my situation and my problem.

We have a mobile react native app which stores into a dynamoDb table one row  each time the users are doing a search. (the database is a search history with a UUID and then the search criteria). On average we have a few thousands new searches into the table every day. The table has just a primary key which is the search id.

The app is quite new but we are reaching the few hundred thousand rows in the table already and can expect having a million in the following months. The data is plain simple data with unique id and string and numbers in the other attributes. No connection, no relationship, etc... That's already when I felt maybe DynamoDb may not have been the best choice but still, I read everywhere it can be suitable for anything if properly managed.

Next to this there is a webapp dashboard which -thanks to a rest api using nodejs lambdas- queries the dynamoDB to make statistics about the searches: how many searches per day, list of last searches... the problem is DynamoDb is not really suitable to query hundred thousands of data (the 1mb limit, query limitations, credits...).
When I do a scan I get only 3000 searches. I tried to make a loop on the scan using the last index requested but after a few test I did not get data and I blocked the maximum throughput. It seems really clear that I don't have the right approach to bring all these searches to my web app. So now what would be the right approach? My ideas are the following but I am open to more experienced one:

- Switching to a SQL database (using the aws migration ?). Will it really be easier then?
- creating lambdas to execute scheduled jobs every night to make statistics every day so that I don't have to query the full database all the time but just some of the most recent searches and the statistics rows? Is it doable? any node.js / lambdas tutorial you may know regarding this?
- better management of indexes? I am still very lost regarding those.

Looking forward to your opinions.

Comment: Usually for analytics you could make a copy of the data in S3 and then use something like Glue, Athena, etc...or even EMR if you have to make aggregation over massive amount of data.
You should look into 'Data lake pattern'

Answer (score 0):

Add another layer to take care for full text search.

For example, with Elasticsearch, or Algolia or other similars.

> Notes:
>
> Elasticsearch may be cost you a lot if compare the cost on dynamodb

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/amazon-dynamodb-elasticsearch-integration/

Comment: As I am querying the full table to make statistics based on it I don't think it would help me too much, unfortunately (not to mention price indeed).

Comment: I am interesting on what solution you will go with finally, but i have the feeling, whatever you try, you would use my way partly or fully, let’s see.

Comment: I am working on lambda running on a schedule every night to make statistics about the day, the stats for each day will be stored in one row and then I'll query only this "satistics" type of rows. Will keep you informed if I succeed.